# How to wait for data factory pipeline to complete the execution?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, signalr, azure-data-factory

net core project. I am calling some ADF(Azure data factory) pipeline using my .net core code as below.

```
 public async Task<string> RunADFPipeline(DataFactoryManagementClient dataFactoryManagementClient, Dictionary<string,object> keyValuePairs, ADFClient aDFClient, string pieplineName)
        {
            CreateRunResponse runResponse = dataFactoryManagementClient.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(aDFClient.ResourceGroupName, aDFClient.DataFactoryName, pieplineName, parameters: keyValuePairs).Result.Body;
            return runResponse.RunId;
        }
```

This pipeline will run for around five minutes and pipeline will write some data to azure sql Db. Now my requirement is to fetch data from sql db. I have couple of questions running around this. How my code will come to know when my pipeline finished excution? I have tried something below.

```
 public async Task<object> GetPipelineInfoAsync(DataFactoryManagementClient dataFactoryManagementClient, ADFClient aDFClient, string runId)
        {
            var info = await dataFactoryManagementClient.PipelineRuns.GetAsync(aDFClient.ResourceGroupName, aDFClient.DataFactoryName, runId);
            return new
            {
                RunId = info.RunId,
                PipelineName = info.PipelineName,
                InvokedBy = info.InvokedBy.Name,
                LastUpdated = info.LastUpdated,
                RunStart = info.RunStart,
                RunEnd = info.RunEnd,
                DurationInMs = info.DurationInMs,
                Status = info.Status,
                Message = info.Message
            };
        }
```

By passing RunId received from first call to above method I can get the status of it. But I cannot wait till the execution completes. The intention is ADF pipeline will write some data to db and that data I need to send back to UI. But I cant wait for this in current call. I am planning to use Signal R for this. As soon as ADF pipeline finishes execution I can call GetPipelineInfoAsync method and if the status is success then I can go to db and fetch details. Only problem I am facing is I cannot block main thread till the adf pipeline finishes execution. Can someone help me how can I fix this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can block the main thread by awaiting on async APIs or using sync APIs. You can't have it both ways though--wait for pipeline success and db updates but not block the main thread. You could issue a refresh upon run success, but until then your UI data will be stale.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the management client's [query by factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.pipelinerunsoperationsextensions.querybyfactory?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.PipelineRunsOperationsExtensions.QueryByFactory);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet) extension API, passing in filters for pipeline name and status (and say a time span):

```
var filters = new PipelineRunFilterParameters
{
    Filters =
    {
        new PipelineRunQueryFilter
        {
            Operand = "PipelineName",
            OperatorProperty = "Equals",
            Values = new List<string> { "my_pipeline", "my_other_pipeline" }
        },
        new PipelineRunQueryFilter
        {
            Operand = "Status",
            OperatorProperty = "Equals",
            Values = new List<string> { "InProgress", "Queued" }
        }
    },
    LastUpdatedBefore = DateTime.Now,
    LastUpdatedAfter = (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
};

while ((_adfClient.PipelineRuns.QueryByFactory(_resourceGroup, _dataFactoryName, filters).Value.Count) >= _maxConcurrentPipelines)
{
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}
```

You can also wait on a single pipeline using the client's response id when creating a run and this API:

```
while ((pipelineRun = _adfClient.PipelineRuns.Get(_resourceGroup, _dataFactoryName, response.RunId)).Status == "InProgress" || pipelineRun.Status == "Queued")
{
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}
```